# Error al desplegar un simple Hola mundo en php en Railway.app

Tags: php, nginx, cloud, error-403

Estoy tratando de desplegar un simple Hola mundo escrito en html dentro de un php en un proyecto de Railway.app

El file es index.php y solo contiene codigo html

```
<h1>Hola mundo </h1>
```

Una vez publicado en github, Railway.app sincroniza el despliegue correctamente.

Entrando con el chrome al dominio de publicación resultante en el proyecto de railway.app se recibe el codigo de error 403 forbidden (nginx/1.22.1)

Aclaración: Si solo le cambio la extensión al file y le pongo index.html, la pagina estática se puede vesualizar perfectamente.
Parece ser que Railway.app no esta haciendo correr el interprete php o que existe algun problema en la plataforma de permisos.

Gracias por la atención a mi pregunta.

Comment: De hecho si el error __403__ es por permisos. Talvez pueda que sea por el directorio donde se encuentra el archivo o algún tipo de configuración.

Comment: Claro. El mismo sitio lo tengo funcionando perfectamente en mi localhost (XAMPP)
luego hago un push en mi repositorio de github y finalmente se sincroniza con Railway.app de manera automatica. Luego railway me informa un dominio publico donde puedo ver como quedo mi despliegue en la nube. Ahi es justamente donde no funciona (403 forbidden). Railway no me da opciones para configurar permisos dentro de su servidor php nginx virtual.